# How do I back up Spore?

Tags: spore

I'm about to move from one computer to another and don't want to lose my Spore save. **How do I back up or transfer a Spore save?**

Previously, I tried copying `...\AppData\Roaming\SPORE` and pasting it into the other computer's AppData, but that consistently crashed the game on startup.

Comment: Have you also copied the "My Spore creations" folder from your "Documents" folder?

Comment: @Kodama that worked! Submit it as an answer :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the save files in `...\AppData\Roaming\SPORE`, you also have to copy the files from the "My Spore Creations" folder from your documents folder. In Windows, that's most likely at `C:\Users\[Username]\Documents\My Spore Creations`.