# I broke my Spore saves

Tags: spore, spore-galactic-adventures

I had to transfer my Spore files from one of my computers to the other so what I did is I sent myself `%appdata%/roaming/spore/game0` and the game file and I just pasted all the files in not knowing anything. I might have replaced a few files with those so now on both computers all my saves are gone even though all the files are there.

How can I get my saves back? What files have to be in the games folder in order for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179551/how-do-i-back-up-spore#:%7E:text=In%20addition%20to%20the%20save,%5D%5CDocuments%5CMy%20Spore%20Creations%20.) answer, have you also copied the 'My Spore Creations' folder from your Documents folder? This, in addition to the AppData files, should ensure everything is copied over.